# How to calculate moments (mean, variance, skewness, kurtosis) of a fitted T distribution in R?

Tags: r, statistics

I've fitted sample data (S&P 500 returns) to a T distribution and now have to calculate the first four moments. However, I am clueless how to approach it, my code looks as:
Which is basically the plot and how I fitted it with rugarch. Is there any way to quickly calculate variance/mean/kurtosis/skewnness? Thanks

```
   library(QRM)
library(rugarch)

dist_st2 <- fitdist("std", training_sample,
                    control=list(tol=1e-20, delta=1e-6))
dist_st2$pars

dist_st2$pars["sigma"]

density_st2 <- ddist(distribution = "std", x,
                     mu = dist_st2$pars["mu"],
                     sigma = dist_st2$pars["sigma"],
                     shape = dist_st2$pars["shape"])

hist(training_sample, freq = FALSE, breaks = 40,
     ylim = c(0, 0.85), xlim = c(-5, 5), border = "gray")


points(x, density_norm, type = "l", lwd = 2, col = COLORS[1])
points(x, density_st2, type = "l", lwd = 2, col = COLORS[2])
lines(density_emp, lwd = 2, lty = 2, col = COLORS[3])
legend("topleft", lty = c(1, 1, 2), col = COLORS[1:3], bty = "n",
       legend = c("Normal distribution", "Student-t distribution",
                  "Empirical distribution"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot say for sure because I am not familiar with the rugarch package and the documentation is a bit superficial. But it seems to me you already have them.

- `dist_st2$pars["mu"]` is the first moment.
- `dist_st2$pars["sigma"]^2` should be the second (please not that you have to square the standard deviation to get the variance).
- `dist_st2$pars["shape"]`is the fourth.
- and there should be `dist_st2$pars["skew"]` which would be the third one.